# Proble ma css y bootstrap con boton que se sobrepone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema con un boton de boostrap 5 que tengo el boton me sale sobre esa caja que tengo del lado derecho y necesito que el boton quede por debajo,  todos los botones q tengo de boostrap  se me posicionan sobre la caja, la caja esta con position fixed

este es el codigo de la caja que sale del lado derecho

```
  .menu_busqueda_act{
   
    opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 0.5s;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 5px;

    }
```

el boton, ps me lo carga el bootstrap pero lo llamo de la siguiente forma.

```
 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Buscar</button>
```

no se si agregandole algo al css del boton o mas bien algo malo que estoy haciendo en el ccs de la caja.

adicional coloco el  html, los dos son llamados por div con ajax.

El filtro que sale allí es el que me llama a content_menu_filtro para que abra y cierre, y el que dice contenedor buscador es quien contiene el botón de búsqueda que se me sobrepone a la caja.

```
<div class="content_market">

<div  id="contenedor_buscador"></div>
  
</div>


<div id="content_menu_filtro"></div>

<a class="filtro-button"><strong>FILTRO</strong><i class="fa fa-filter fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que ya había visto esta pregunta con la misma imagen, y alguien te recomendó revisar el tema de z-index. Eliminaste la anterior pregunta? Se votó para cierre? Por favor revisa: [ask]

Comment: La anterior me decia que faltaba contenido y por eso se cerro, entonces le coloque el codigo para q lo vieran, la persona me dijo q podia ser algo de z-index pero no use el z-index, alli coloque el codigo y el botton de boostrap  ps no se el ccs que usa por que coloco como dicen ellos en su documentación  para llamarlo por defecto